# How do I select the count of a specific value without grouping in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a view that's a result of a UNION of two selects. It has contents similar to this:

```
id foreignkey
1  a
2  a
3  b
4  c
```

I'm looking to add a column in the view's definition that will show a count for the values, but without aggregating them. Somthing like this:

```
id foreignkey count
1  a          2
2  a          2
3  b          1
4  c          1
```

my existing query is basically:

```
create or replace view x as
select * from a
union
select * from b
```

I want the count on the result of the union but I"m not sure how to do that.

EDIT - made some progress, with a normal table I can do this:

```
SELECT *,
 (select count(id) from mytable where t.data = data)
FROM mytable as t
```

The problem comes into play because the table is really a union of two tables. Not sure how to do it without doing the union twice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a window function:

```
create or replace view x 
as
select id, foreignkey, count(*) over (partition by foreignkey) as fk_count
from (
  select id, foreignkey from a
  union
  select id, foreignkey from b
) x;
```

---

Unrelated, but:

UNION removes duplicates from the result, UNION ALL does not. If you know there are now duplicates, then you should be using UNION ALL because it's faster.

Comment: Worked great, thanks! I had to add an alias to the subquery though but otherwise perfect.